# 編集の査読に関するメッセージが未翻訳

Tags: バグ, 翻訳

レビューなしでの編集権限が無い状態で編集を行うと編集画面上部にメッセージが表示されますが、タイトル以外が英語のままです。

> あなたの編集は、査読されるまでキューに入れられます。
> We welcome edits that make the post easier to understand and more valuable for readers. Because community members review edits, please try to make the post substantially better than how you found it, for example, by fixing grammar or adding additional resources and hyperlinks.

また、編集後にレビュー待ちである旨が表示されますが、それも英語です。

> Thanks for submitting an edit. It is only visible to you until it’s been approved by trusted community members

Answer (score 4, accepted):

以下の string たちのようでした。

- https://ja.traducir.win/strings/11337
- https://ja.traducir.win/strings/13129
- https://ja.traducir.win/strings/13130
- https://ja.traducir.win/strings/13126

@supa さんが翻訳を提案してくださり、先ほど私が承認したので、1 週間以内には翻訳が反映されるはずです。