# 質問を編集したときに、未翻訳の文章が現れる

Tags: バグ, 翻訳

他人の質問をレビューキューにアクセスできない状態（信用度350以下）で編集したところ、「確認されるまでキューに入れられます」のようなメッセージが表示されましたが、
「ありがとうございます」、の後の部分の文章が

> it is only visible to you until it's been approved by trusted community members.

というふうに、翻訳されていない文字が出てきています。
これは仕様なのでしょうか？それとも本来翻訳されるべき場所なのでしょうか？

既存の質問でしたらすみません。

**出てきた画像：**
[image: 未翻訳画像]

Comment: 関連：[編集の査読に関するメッセージが未翻訳](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3417/2767)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

該当の文字列に対する翻訳を追加しておきました。実際に反映されるまでは多少タイムラグがあるので (恐らく数日程度) 、しばらく待ってから確認してみてください。

https://ja.traducir.win/strings/15767

---

スタックオーバーフローのサイト内で使われるメッセージは、英語版を元にコミュニティメンバーがボランティアで翻訳を行っています。
翻訳が追いついていない箇所や、原文が見直されたのに伴い (一度は翻訳したけど) 英語に戻っているような箇所が時々出てきます。もし気になる箇所を見つけたら、まずは今回のようにメタにて報告を行ってもらえれば OK です。

興味があれば翻訳の提案にあなた自身も参加することができますので、以下の投稿も参考にしてください。

[サイトを翻訳するための新ツールの提案: Traducir](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2750)