# サイトに未翻訳の部分が複数ある

Tags: バグ, 翻訳

文章が未翻訳の部分をいくつか見つけたので、こちらで質問をさせていただきます。
以前[質問](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3726/%e8%b3%aa%e5%95%8f%e3%82%92%e7%b7%a8%e9%9b%86%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%a8%e3%81%8d%e3%81%ab-%e6%9c%aa%e7%bf%bb%e8%a8%b3%e3%81%ae%e6%96%87%e7%ab%a0%e3%81%8c%e7%8f%be%e3%82%8c%e3%82%8b)したとき[traducir.win](https://ja.traducir.win)を使えば良いと教えてもらったのですが、まだこのサイトに登録して半年にも満たない人間が何か手を加えてしまうのはなーと思い、質問させてもらってます。

現状として、私が今回見つけた未翻訳の部分は以下の3つです。

- プロフィルページにおいて、他のstackexchangeアカウントが表示されているところ(1つのコミュニティーはサイトには反映されない設定で）で、`1 hidden accounts`と未翻訳([https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/00000/ユーザー名](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/00000/%E3%83%A6%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B6%E3%83%BC%E5%90%8D) のページ)
- 他人の質問を即座に編集し反映できる信用度を持ってないため編集が承認待ちの時、「新着質問」や「新着回答」のレビューキューでその質問を見たら`Pending edit`と未翻訳
- 銀バッジや金バッジを獲得してない時にバッジ一覧を見ると`You don't have a gold(silver) badge yet.　〜〜`と未翻訳

細かいところもあるのですが、こんな感じです。
写真の大きさの都合上1部の写真はカットさせてもらっているのですが、わかりますでしょうか？必要なら写真を全画面写します。

**バッジhidden未翻訳:**
[image: バッジhidden未翻訳]

**レビューキュー未翻訳:**
[image: レビューキュー未翻訳]

**バッジ未翻訳：**
[image: バッジ未翻訳]

Comment: traducir.win での翻訳は即反映されるわけではなく、いったんレビュワーによる確認が行われるのでそこまで慎重にならなくても大丈夫です。(案を出してもらえるだけでも歓迎です)

Comment: @cubick そうなのですか！初めて知りました。教えていただきありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下の strings でそれぞれ翻訳を入力しておきました。もし訳がイマイチなものがあれば翻訳提案を出してもらえればと思います。

#### アカウントページ

n 個のアカウトが非表示
https://ja.traducir.win/strings/15710

#### レビューキュー

"Pending edit" -> "編集待ち" だと少し分かりづらいかと思い、"編集の承認待ち" としてみました。

https://ja.traducir.win/strings/15536
https://ja.traducir.win/strings/15535

#### バッジ

金
https://ja.traducir.win/strings/15551
銀
https://ja.traducir.win/strings/14540
銅
https://ja.traducir.win/strings/14591
ボタン
https://ja.traducir.win/strings/14594